# Transformation of confidence interval

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

> Let $X\sim  \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$. Given a simple random sample I know that
>   $$\left[\bar X - z_{1- \alpha/2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}},\bar X + z_{1- \alpha/2} \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}\right]$$
>   is a $1-\alpha$ confidence interval for $\mu$.

What will be the new confidence interval for $\tau(\mu)=\dfrac{e^\mu}{1+e^\mu}$?

Comment: What are $\tau$ and $\mu$?

Comment: $\mu$ is the mean of normal distribution $X\sim  \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $\tau$ is a function of $\mu$ $\tau(\mu)=\dfrac{e^\mu}{1+e^\mu}$.

Comment: To determine a confidence interval, we need a probability distribution, such as $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. $\tau$ is not a probability distribution. Can you clarify?

Comment: Now that I'm seeing the title again, I'm starting to think that $\tau$ may be the transformation function $\tau(x)=\dfrac{e^x}{1+e^x} = \dfrac{1}{e^{-x}+1}$. In that case the transformed confidence interval would be the transformed lower boundary combined with the transformed upper boundary. Note that its expectation will be different from $\tau(\mu)$.

Comment: @IlikeSerena Thanks.